# Bash float calculations from last line in a file

Tags: python, bash, variables, floating-point, calculator

I have a file text.txt as follows:

```
A       B        C    D      E    F   G   F 
1.1     2        3    4      5    6   7   8 
1.2    20        30   40     50   60  70  80 
6.3    70.5      10   20.5   10   20  10  30
```

I want read the last line res=[6.3    70.5      10   20.5   10   20  10  30] and do  float calculations such as sum all columns except the first two  sum([10   20.5   10   20  10  30]) so that ans=100.5;  multiple first column 6.3 by 10 and add 2 ans=65; and so on

```
#!/bin/bash

# Input file name
echo -n "File Name: "
read SO

# Read data
res=$(tail -n 1  $SO) #Read last line 
res=($res)            #Convert string to number
echo $res

#Float calculations 
python -c "print sum($res[2:])"
python -c "print $res[0]*10+2)"
```

The code is working expect for the float calculations which give syntax error. My question is how to pass array $res to python? Or is there an easy way to do this float calculation given array $res ?

Comment: bash doesn't support floating point arithmetics. Python variables are different to shell variables.

Comment: awk could be much simpler for your task: `awk 'END{for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) t+=$i; print t, $1*10+2}' text.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to to save the output as array of numbers to perform many other calculations

Comment: @BERKO Could you please tell me why you don’t want to write the whole script in python then? I showed how you can do your calcs in pure bash. Why don’t you want to use it in that case?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could do to get the variable to Python. You can pass it as arguments or you could also have python read in that line via sys.stdin.

Pass the line as arguments to python:

```
$ bar=$(tail -1 numbers.txt )
$ echo $bar
6.3 70.5 10 20.5 10 20 10 30
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.argv" $bar
['-c', '6.3', '70.5', '10', '20.5', '10', '20', '10', '30']
```

Pass the line via stdin:

```
$ echo "$bar" | python -c "import sys; print sys.argv; print sys.stdin.read()" 
['-c']
6.3    70.5      10   20.5   10   20  10  30
```

Note that these values are strings and you'll need to convert them to a float() before attempting any math operations on them. Also with the second option you'll have to split the line and then convert them to a float.

For extra fun with the stdin route, have a look at: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fileinput.html

I'd recommend that you write a python script instead of using `python -c` as it can get unruly fairly quick. Name the script: process_numbers.py,  with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
# quick list comprehension to convert args to floats
numbers = [float(i) for i in sys.argv[1:]]
print numbers
print numbers[0]*10 + 2
```

Then, in your bash script:

```
python process_numbers.py $(tail -1 numbers.txt)
[6.3, 70.5, 10.0, 20.5, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 30.0]
65.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I try python -c "import sys; print sys.argv" $bar; float(bar) is gives an error.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, in short the float() needs to be in the python code not in bash. I've updated my answer to show how you would do that in a python script.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a necessity to run python for such simple calculations?

You can run [bc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)) for that operation. It's the most common way to make calculations in bash, especially for float numbers.

You can do something like:

```
res=(6.3 70.5 10 20.5 10 20 10 30)
echo ${res[@]:2} | tr ' ' + | bc
echo "${res[0]} * 10 + 2" | bc
```